# Is the Number of Photons Inversely Proportional to the Wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

I was rearranging the equation for the energy of a wave in terms of the number of a photons in the wave, and velocity,  and found that:
starting with:
$$
nhv=E
$$
$$
E/nh=v
$$
$$
E/nh=fλ
$$
$$
E=nhfλ
$$
$$
hf=nhfλ
$$
$$
hf/hf=1
$$
$$
1=nλ
$$
therefore,
$$
n=λ^{-1} or λ=n^{-1}
$$
is this correct, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight mistake which comes from the way you defined $E$. The $v$ in the equation $E = nhv$ is the frequency not the velocity. If it helps, I would suggest using $E = \hbar\omega$ to avoid this notational confusion. Also, keep in mind $E=n\hbar\omega$ will give you the *total* energy, not the energy per particle. I.e., $E_{tot}=n\hbar\omega$, $E_{photon}=\hbar\omega$